# How to get paypal advance or pro sandbox account

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I want to integrate paypal payment without redirect to there site ,so what is best out of these two and how i get advance or pro sandbox account for testing ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Pro, then you can keep the buyer on your site the entire time.  The buyer will not be redirected to PayPal or have to log into a PayPal account to make a payment.  If you want to test with Pro, you would need to create a developer account at [developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/).  Then once you have a developer account, you can use the account that is created for you by default (facilitator account.  After logging in, click the tab for "Applications".  Then click on the link on the left that says "Sandbox accounts".  This will show you any of your sandbox accounts that you have set up and that you can use for testing.

If this is your first time, you should see just one and it will have the word "facilitator" in the email address.  By default this account should have pro enabled, however I have seen a few that did not have pro enabled by default.  If your account does not, you can either try adding it on your self by logging into that test account and signing up for pro, or you can provide me with the email address of that particular account and I can try to enable it on my end.

Another option would be to try to create a new test account by clicking the blue button on the top right that says "Create Account".  Once you have your accounts set up, you will just plug your Sandbox API credentials into your code and point towards the sandbox instead of the live site.  The [Sandbox User Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/) can be useful as well.